# Why doesn't the javascript code in the php code execute when the image is clicked?

Tags: php, html

In the code below, you can see that when the image is supposed to be displayed, I have made a condition that the javascript function will be executed when the user clicks on the image, but this does not happen.

```
  <?php
// خواندن تمام توضیحات عکس‌ها از فایل
$imageData = file_get_contents('manuscripts.txt');

// جدا کردن توضیحات هر عکس
$images = explode("\n\n", $imageData);

// بررسی گزینه انتخاب شده و نمایش عکس‌های مربوطه
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $selectedOption = $_POST['option'];
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image = explode("\n", $image);
        if (count($image) >= 3) { // تعداد خطوط توضیحات به 3 تغییر کرده است
            $imagePath = explode(": ", $image[0])[1];
            $description = explode(": ", $image[1])[1];
            $about = implode("\n", array_slice($image, 2));

            // براساس گزینه انتخاب شده، عکس‌ها را نمایش دهید
            if ($selectedOption === 'all' ||
                ($selectedOption === 'habib-allah' && $description === 'habib-allah') ||
                ($selectedOption === 'mohammad-reza' && $description === 'mohammad-reza')) {
                  
            echo "<div class='image-container'>";
            echo "<img src='".$imagePath."' alt='".$description."' onclick='showDescription(\"".htmlspecialchars($about)."\")'><br>";
            echo "</div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
 else {
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image = explode("\n", $image);
        if (count($image) >= 3) {
            $imagePath = explode(": ", $image[0])[1];
            $description = explode(": ", $image[1])[1];
            $about = implode("\n", array_slice($image, 2));
           
            echo "<div class='image-container'>";
            echo "<img src='".$imagePath."' alt='".$description."'onclick='showDescription(\"".htmlspecialchars($about)."\")'><br>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}



?>

<script>
function showDescription(about) {
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.style.width = "100%";
    overlay.style.height = "100%";
    overlay.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    overlay.style.position = "fixed";
    overlay.style.top = "0";
    overlay.style.left = "0";
    overlay.style.display = "flex";
    overlay.style.justifyContent = "center";
    overlay.style.alignItems = "center";

    var descriptionBox = document.createElement("div");
    descriptionBox.style.width = "50%";
    descriptionBox.style.height = "50%";
    descriptionBox.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    descriptionBox.style.padding = "20px";
    descriptionBox.style.overflow = "scroll";

    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    closeButton.innerText = "بستن";
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        overlay.remove();
    });

    var descriptionText = document.createElement("p");
    descriptionText.innerHTML = about;
    
    descriptionBox.appendChild(descriptionText);
    descriptionBox.appendChild(closeButton);
    overlay.appendChild(descriptionBox);

    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}
</script>



</div>
```

I realized that when at the end of the variable about
[1] I let the JavaScript code run, but it displays only one letter
But I want the entire about variable to be executed inside the JavaScript code

Comment: As a basic test I hardcoded values into the above HTML to test the Javascript - that worked fine so whatever your issue it is likely caused by the data you supply as an argument to the `showDescription` function. It would be easier for others to diagnose/test if you added the rendered HTML rather than the raw PHP with no data.

Comment: try php echo for your about variable to check if it is exactly what you expect!?

Comment: Most likely your description contains a line break, which will invalidate the JS syntax at this point then. You should use `json_encode` to handle data that you want to output into a template _as_ valid JS code - see duplicate. (Keep in mind that JSON-encoding is still likely to produce `"` in the output, so keep applying `htmlspecialchars` on top to escape those.)